# Слайдер фотографий на Drupal7

Tags: drupal

Как сделать такой слайдер фотографий на drupal 7(фотографии добавляются через viwes).есть готовые модули?
пытался  использовать jquery ui slider,но так как знаний в jquery нет,то не получается(
Вот что щас есть на данный момент(http://banya.sctraduga.ru/bath , в идеале должно получиться как здесь(http://oooplastika.ru(внизу страницы слайдер)).
помогите кто чем может)

Answer (score 1):

можно через [jcarousel](https://drupal.org/project/jcarousel) попробовать. но придется со скинами повозится, либо свой js в шаблон вставлять.